# How to get input name element with multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I need to element get the same multidimensional array by name or id in jQuery as a variable.

```
<input type="text" id="minrange_1" placeholder="Minimum Range" name="range[][min]">
<input type="text" id="maxrange_1" placeholder="Maximum Range" name="range[][max]">
<input type="text" id="rates_1" placeholder="Rates ($)" name="range[][rate]" >
<input type="text" id="minrange_2" placeholder="Minimum Range" name="range[][min]">
<input type="text" id="maxrange_2" placeholder="Maximum Range" name="range[][max]">
<input type="text" id="rates_2" placeholder="Rates ($)" name="range[][rate]" >
```

***Output need***

```
value = [minrange_value, mxarange_value, rate_value]
```

**OR**

```
vaulue = [
0 => {minrange=> minrange value, maxrange => mxarange_value, rate=>rate_value }
]
```

Comment: vanilla tip: `document.getElementById("id").value`

Comment: Duplicate IDs are a bad idea. Use class instead

Comment: The id is not duplicate in unique

Answer (score 0):

```
    var minvalue = jQuery("input[name='range[][min]']").map(function(){return jQuery(this).val();}).get();
    var maxvalue = jQuery("input[name='range[][max]']").map(function(){return jQuery(this).val();}).get();
    var ratevalue = jQuery("input[name='range[][rate]']").map(function(){return jQuery(this).val();}).get();
var range = [];
for(var i=0; i<= minvalue.length;i++){
    var r = []; 
    r['min'] = minvalue[i];
    r['max'] = maxvalue[i];
    r['rate'] = ratevalue[i];
    range.push(r);
}
```